# API Discord HTTPS запросы не используя библиотек

Tags: php, api, discord, https, discord-api

Нужно реализовать запросы к серверу Discord, напрямую не используя библиотек.

А конкретно реализовать отправку сообщения на канал.

Скорей всего это не то что мне нужно, но прикреплю ссылку
https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/networking#sendmessage

В API все что я нашел это как авторизоваться и как использовать методы

Но я не нашел как передавать данные (get, post), на какие ссылки передавать данные, как передать токен бота.

Не могли бы вы пожалуйста помочь, в интернете не смог найти примеры реализации напрямую с помощью PHP

Comment: Чем обусловлен отказ от библиотек?

Comment: Используй свой личный сайтовый движок, не хочу нагружать сервер разными библиотеками компосерам и тд. Мне надо просто делать постинг с сайта в Дискорд

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#authorizing-your-application https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2 - это авторизация, https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message - отправка сообщения

Comment: @СашаАдамов Это конечно хорошо, что вы хотите разобраться с АПИ дискорда на более низком уровне. Но с чего это вы решили, что ваш функционал будет работать быстрее чем какая-нибудь сторонняя библиотека? (к слову их можно подключить и без композера)